# Only first command of makefile is executed

Tags: makefile

I have following makefile:

```
main.o: ServerSocket/main.cpp ../Shared/socket.h 
    g++ -c ServerSocket/main.cpp  -lstdc++

DriveInfo.o: ServerSocket/DriveInfo.cpp ServerSocket/DriveInfo.h ServerSocket/Consts.h
    g++ -c ServerSocket/DriveInfo.cpp  -lstdc++

ProcessInfo.o: ServerSocket/ProcessInfo.cpp ServerSocket/ProcessInfo.h ServerSocket/Consts.h
    g++ -c ServerSocket/ProcessInfo.cpp  -lstdc++

thread_pool.o: ServerSocket/thread_pool.cpp ServerSocket/thread_pool.h 
DriveInfo.o ProcessInfo.o thread_pool.o
server: main.o 
    g++ -o server main.o 
DriveInfo.o ProcessInfo.o thread_pool.o
```

Problem is  only one command of that file is being executed, so if I want to execute the next one< I have to delete or comment previous command. What is wrong with this makefile?

Comment: Since this question really has nothing to do with C++ aside from the fact that the files in question are compiled using gcc, I removed the [C++] tag.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Make execute by default the first rule you provide it.

You want to create a rule that execute all the rules you provide

```
all : main.o DriveInfo.o ProcessInfo.o thread_pool.o
```

and place it at the begin of your Makefile or call it with `make all`

Comment: This is a good guide out there for more information - https://makefiletutorial.com/

Answer (score 5):

This is by design. You can tell `make` which targets to build:

```
make main.o DriveInfo.o
```

will build these two targets. Alternatively, if you want `make` by default to build all (or some) targets, you can specify a rule *at the beginning of the Makefile* stating that:

```
all: main.o DriveInfo.o …
```

Now, `make all` (or just `make`) will build all dependent targets. It’s also good practice to declare `all` as a [phony target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) to tell `make` that it doesn’t correspond to an actually existing file. Do this by putting `.PHONY: all` in the Makefile.

A final remark, the name `all` is arbitrary. You could use any other name here but `all` is conventional. The important part is that it’s the *first* rule in your Makefile if you want it to be the one that’s executed when you call `make` without any explicit targets.